# jquery addition is not showing in view page source

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am changing domain name for url by jQuery, it's working when page is loading but when I am doing view page source the addition is not showing.

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var hname= location.hostname;
    var linkRewriter = function(a, b, c) {
        if(hname=="www.somesite.com"){
            $('a[href*="' + a + '"]').each(function() {
                $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href').replace(a, b));
            });
        }
        linkRewriter('https://www.somesite1.com/', 'https://www.somesite2.com/'); 
    });
});
```

Comment: using view page source would show the actual html.... but try inspecting the element....

Comment: Should it be `function(a,b)` and not `function(a,b,c)`.

Comment: @PraveenKumar that's not necessary point here....

Answer (score 2):

The reason it isn't showing the new urls is that browsers show the source as it was downloaded from the server. They show the raw source from cache or by re-requesting it in response to the "view source" command.

If JavaScript has modified part of the source, the original source will still contain the original values.

If you want to take a look at the current, modified, page source, take a look at your browser's development tools:

- [Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/index)
- [Firefox](https://getfirebug.com/)
- [IE](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359)
- [Safari](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/)

On most modern browsers, if you right-click the select box, you'll have an "Inspect" or "Inspect Element" menu option that will open the dev tools and navigate to that element in the DOM inspector.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the "View page source" display the content from the file saved. That is, the "view page source" display the source code of the file which you are running on the browser, it does not show the code which changed through javascript or through other source.

Comment: Can we check and capture domain name for a src by xslt??

Comment: Are you asking about capturing it through asp.net? Please go through the link http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JAXPXSLT6.html